# The websocket messages in my online game are being served too slow

Tags: python, web, websocket, lag, extrapolation

Im attempting to make a online game in python, though I have ran into a problem. Basically I want the game to be playable in many regions, but the websockets are to laggy to be played in farther regions. To get around this I have implemented a system on the client that extrapolates between two values to find the speed (x and y axis change). The player will continue to move to these speeds, so if there is a lag spike, it wont be as noticeable. the server is coded in python, I use a python web-framework called Quart (flask with asyncio functions) The websockets run asynchronously to the main loop. The main problem is when the x and y values are updated on the server, they might be updated multiple times before they get served by the websocket; The result of this is an inaccurate estimate on the client side, which cause jittery movement when the clients x and y values are updated to the proper values. I would appreciate advice for resolving this issue.

**Things to note:**

The python web-framework I use is documented here:  https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/

My method for extrapolating the values on the client-side is just recording the before and after x and y values, then subtracting the before from the after.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on why "multiple updates before they get served by the websocket" cause "inaccurate estimates" and "jittery movement"? It is not really clear from your question why this would be the case and how exactly that problem would manifest on the player's screen. Keep in mind that there are many, many different ways to handle position updates in game netcode. The solution which seemed most straight-forward to you might not be the one others think about when they read your question.

Comment: @Philipp, To put it simply, when you push down an arrow key, a message is sent from the client to the server. The server will respond by adding a certain value to the current x value (the movement speed). But since my web sockets are asynchronous, this may happen multiple times before the websocket responds to the client. As a result, the client may receive  updated coords where the value subtracted or added is higher than it should be (e.g. it should be receiving the current coords minus 1, but it receives the coords minus 4). The jittering is caused by extrapolating from these coords.